# galang : type interface {} does not support indexing

Tags: go

am getting the following error , when am trying add map to interface :

invalid operation: msgs["Application"]["instance-id"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)

application :

```
resultChannel := make(chan map[string]interface{})
    clients := make(map[string][]map[string]interface{})

    go func(clients map[string][]map[string]interface{}){
        for {
            msgs := <- resultChannel
            url := "http://xxxxxx/results/"+msgs["instance-id"].(string)
            res,err := http.Get(url)

            if err != nil{
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            body,err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
            if err != nil{
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            s, err := getResults([]byte(body))

            for i := range s {
                clientResults := map[string]interface{}{
                    s[i].Check.Name:s[i].Status,
                }

                clients[msgs["Application"]["instance-id"]["checks"]]=append(clients[msgs["Application"]["instance-id"]["checks"]],clientResults)

            }

        }
    }(clients)






for i := range s{
        if len(s[i].Application) > 0{
            clientMap := map[string]interface{}{
            "instance-id":s[i].Name,
            "Division":s[i].Division,
            "Status":2,
            "Application":s[i].Application,
            "checks":make(map[string]interface{}),
            }
            clients[s[i].Application]=append(clients[s[i].Application],clientMap)
            resultChannel <- clientMap
        }

        }
```

am not sure what is the best way to handle such case . at the end i need to have the following structure :

```
[
 application_name[instance-id:xxxxx Division:xxxxx Status:2 Application:fulfilment checks:[xxxxx:0,yyyy:1]] 
 application_name[instance-id:xxxxx Division:xxxxx Status:2 Application:fulfilment checks:[xxxxx:0,yyyy:1]]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct type to represent the data 
and use that struct instead of interface{} in the map data types. There is no need to use interface{} in this case.

For example:

```
type Client struct {
        InstanceId string
        Division string
        Status int
        Application string
        Checks map[string]int
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details , am still new to go language .. i have tried to create a new struct you mentioned , still having same error